# DAX to Adjust Value Based on Two Filters and compare previously selected year

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an issue where I'm trying to create a table where the dates are course start dates, so they are very much Non-Consecutive. I was able to [follow this video](https://youtu.be/JBN-x2duxSU?si=QBKCqqi2vSZeTrL3) and their website to get the data to show previous amounts for one course at a time, but no matter how I adapt the code, I can't get it to show the correct value if I have more than one course selected at a time, I'll show you what I mean:

Here is what I want to have happen:

| Course Start Date | Course ID | Passing Rate | Previous Passing Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/11/2023 | Engl | 75% | 80% |
| 04/11/2023 | Engl | 80% | 65% |
| 01/25/2023 | Engl | 65% |  |
| 08/11/2023 | Math | 91% | 52% |
| 04/11/2023 | Math | 52% | 78% |
| 01/25/2023 | Math | 78% |  |
| 08/11/2023 | Hist | 72% | 61% |
| 04/11/2023 | Hist | 61% | 88% |
| 01/25/2023 | Hist | 88% |  |

When I ONLY have Engl or I ONLY have Math selected this works, BUT once I select more than one Course ID it breaks! It was originally averaging the last column answers, so I updated the DAX. But now it's just shifting the answers up one, Here is what my DAX Looks like Right now for the Previous Passing Rate Column

```
Previous Passing Rate=
var CurrentYearMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Course Info Table'[YearMonth])

var PreviousYearMonth = CALCULATE(
MAX('Course Info Table'[YearMonth]),
ALLSELECTED('Course Info Table'),
KEEPFILTERS('Course Info Table'[YearMonth] < CurrentYearMonth), KEEPFILTERS('Course Info Table'[Course ID]='Course Info Table'[Course ID]))

var result = CALCULATE([Passing Rate], ALLSELECTED('Course Info Table'), 'Course Info Table'[YearMonth] = PreviousYearMonth)

return
result
```

And this is what I get:

| Course Start Date | Course ID | Passing Rate | Previous Passing Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 08/11/2023 | Engl | 75% | 52% |
| 04/11/2023 | Engl | 80% | 78% |
| 01/25/2023 | Engl | 65% |  |
| 08/11/2023 | Math | 91% | 61% |
| 04/11/2023 | Math | 52% | 88% |
| 01/25/2023 | Math | 78% |  |
| 08/11/2023 | Hist | 72% | 80% |
| 04/11/2023 | Hist | 61% | 65% |
| 01/25/2023 | Hist | 88% |  |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg4rq.png)
All of the previous passing rates are shifted up one course! It will do this no matter how many or how few course id's I have selected they all shift up one and the top rates go to the bottom course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your result line, you will also need to filter on the Course ID.
Try something like:

```
Previous Passing Rate=
  var CurrentYearMonth = SELECTEDVALUE('Course Info Table'[YearMonth])
  var courseId = SELECTEDVALUE('Course Info Table'[Course ID])

  var PreviousYearMonth = CALCULATE(
    MAX('Course Info Table'[YearMonth]),
    ALLSELECTED('Course Info Table'),
    KEEPFILTERS('Course Info Table'[YearMonth] < CurrentYearMonth), 
    KEEPFILTERS('Course Info Table'[Course ID] = courseId)
  )

  var result = CALCULATE([Passing Rate], ALLSELECTED('Course Info Table'), 'Course Info Table'[YearMonth] = PreviousYearMonth && 'Course Info Table'[Course ID] = courseId)

  return
    result
```

Comment: We're getting closer! But this change still gives the problem of before, where it just moves the results to the wrong course. Funny enough, I even tried in the results to put in 'Course Info Table'[Course ID] = "Math" and it still listed them on the wrong line next to the other course.

Comment: Updated the answer above, should now work. I changed `KEEPFILTERS('Course Info Table'[Course ID]='Course Info Table'[Course ID])` to `KEEPFILTERS('Course Info Table'[Course ID] = courseId)`

Comment: SAM!!! You win all of the cookies!! Thank you SO MUCH!! I'm going to level with you, when I replied before I didn't see that you had made courseId a var up above, so I was putting in an actual course id. THANK YOU!!